# Push notification using cloud messaging firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using cloud messaging from firebase with my android app, I am trying to receive a realtime update without refreshing the activity and getting data from the database, so when a user sends another user a message, this last user will receive a notification, anyone knows how to guide me in the right direction?

Comment: you want  to do something kinda like whatsapp ?

Comment: hey werokk ! how do you implement notification in cloud messaging , have you done without running service? , please reply i have some doubts !

Comment: yes something like whatsapp

Comment: I use the firebase database service and cloud messaging, so the messages get stored in the database and that's where I get them from!

Answer (score 0):

In the Firebase service `FirebaseMessagingService` you implement the method `onMessageReceived` in such a way that lets you update the chat based on the infos in the notification.

For example, to get the data needed from the notification message:

```
String sender = null;
int chatId;
String msg = null;
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //YOU NEED TO USE DATA MESSAGES TO CARRY ALL THE INFORMATION ABOUT THE MESSAGE
    Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    title = data.get("sender");
    msg = data.get("body");
    chatId = data.get("chatId");
    //this function implements the updating of the chat with the new message received
    updateChat(chatId,sender,msg);
}
```

This code example is based on a push notification message data payload that looks like:

```
{
    "Message": {
            "Token": client_device_token,
            "Data": {
                    "sender": "John",
                    "chatId": chatId_between_me_and_Jhon,
                    "body": "Hi you, this is John"
                    }
                }

 }
```

The implementation of the method `updateChat(chatId,sender,msg)` is up to you and depends on the logic of your app and your database.